# Using multiprocessing on macOS vs. Windows

Tags: python, windows, macos, python-multiprocessing

I'm using multiprocessing.pool and I use macOS by default, but I also need to try it on Windows. It runs perfectly on macOS, however when I try to run on windows it just displays unlimited error messages... and I can't even kill the program.

I've seen that the start method on windows is 'spawn' and on macOS is 'fork' by default. Is this the problem? If yes, how can I solve it?

Part of the code below:

```
        pool = Pool(processes = numprocs)
        # evaluate fitness of particles in swarm
        swarm = pool.map_async(partial(proxy, costf = costFunc, i=i),Swarm)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        pool.terminate()

        Swarm = swarm.get()
```

**EDIT1:**

I was able to get the error message, my bad.

```
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error messages?

Comment: No sorry, the error messages are infinite... :/

Comment: Only copy and paste a sample then..

Comment: Is your main protected by 'if __name__ == "__main__"'?

Comment: I could get it sorry. Edited original post with error message.

Comment: @Kefeng91 no, it should be?

Comment: Yes, it should. I don't know if it is the reason your code does not work on Windows, but multiprocessing needs to know which file is your main to import it (especially on Windows as it spawns a new interpreter, while it forks the current one on Mac and Linux). Nevertheless, always protect your main with 'if __name__ == "__main__"'.

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__' ` ;)